# QGIS crashed after loading project?

Tags: qgis

5-15 seconds after loading a big project, QGIS crashes. QGIS draws the project data to the screen and seems ready with that, after this  get a "qgis-bin.exe has stopped working".

Is there any good way to start digging into the problem?

I have:

- Uninstalled and re-installed QGIS, including removing the .qgis folder and all regedit entries for QGIS.
- Manually tried to go through the project .qgs file to look for bigger noticable inconsistenies.
- Tried both with the current 2.18.3 version and with older versions of QGIS (2.16.3, 2.14.11)

The problem started right after I had messed around with the print composer atlas generator to try to get a print layout to work, and after I installed the plugin Grids for Atlas - but removing the .qgis folder and uninstalling qgis should remove all traces of this? The projects consists of around 15 shapefiles 1Mb-30Mb. Any other projects work well except for this.

I find no way to enable a log file or find a crash dump when googling. There was a few weeks work with layouting for this project.

Environment: QGIS 2.18.3/2.16.3/2.14.11, Windows 10, i7 processor, 16Gb memory, 550Gb free SSD HD.

Comment: Sometimes the project is corrupted and you have to rebuild it. I have seen that some times open the project in a small window (instead o full screen) prevents some crashes. But if the project has problems this is not enought.